# How to pass s3 object names getting from the lambda events as a parameters to the AWS Glue Workflow

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue3.0

I have an S3 bucket that will trigger invoking a lambda function based on the put event type. Then the lambda function will trigger the Glue workflow. In the Glue workflow, I have created one glue job that converts XLSX files to CSV. This is the overall scenario. Now I will fetch uploaded object names(XLSX files) based on the lambda event. But how can I pass these object names to the Glue job once lambda trigger to the Glue workflow? Can I pass object names one after another to the job dynamically once the workflow starts so that all the files will convert at one shot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lambda function handler's one of parameter is `event` and other is `context`.
Event parameter structure is depend on invoking Service.
For S3 service you can find event structure at [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html).

```
event.Records[0].s3.object.key
```

is your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the time to reply. But here my concern is different. As I mentioned earlier in my question that I can get the list of object names from the lambda event. After getting those list of object names, how can I pass that list as a parameter to glue workflow?

Comment: You need to trigger workflow. See: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_trigger 

`create_trigger` take `Actions.Arguments` take parameters.

Full example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-calling.html